# WCF Service not accepting multiple body parameters

Tags: wcf, rest, ria

I have OpenRIA WCF Service hosted within an asp.net website. I have a WPF client that connects to the Authentiction and DomainService. I am having trouble calling the Login method. It basically does not like that the message parameters are not "Wrapped". See the error message below

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.dll Additional information: Operation 'Login' of contract 'IPatientAuthenticationDomainServiceContract' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped. On the client side, The WebHttpBehavior in domainClient.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors has DefaultBodyStyle = Wrapped*

The asp.net project that's hosting the OpenRIA services has web behavior set to Wrapped.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

What could I be missing? Has anyone encountered this issue?

A possible workaround is to change the method parameters to accept a complex type but I do not have control over the Login method of the AuthenticationService. It is part of a base class that RIA framework provides.

Thanks,

Ankur

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. Just wanted to share the fix. I am using SharedCookieContainer that Kyle McClellan wrote for sharing cookie between Auth service and Domain service when not using an in-browser client. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/05/14/ria-services-authentication-out-of-browser.aspx

The SharedCookieBehavior in this code is an extension of WebHttpBehavior. This class needs to have the DefaultBodyStyle set to Wrapped when its newed up. Simple fix but took me a while to figure out.

Thanks,

Ankur